# PyTest : Allow Failure Rate

Tags: python, pytest

I am currently working on a project where we are running a large suite of parameterized tests (>1M). The tests are randomly generated use-cases and in this large test space, it is expected that in each run certain edge cases will fail, ~1-2%. Is there a implementation for Pytest where you can pass a failure-rate argument, or handle this behavior?

Comment: Sorry @georgexsh. I have been travelling all week. The hotfix you suggested does seem work and is certainly a good implementation. I will have more feedback in the coming week.

Comment: hey any feedback?

Answer (score 7):

I guess what you want is modify exit status of `pytest` command, there is a [nonpublic hook](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/3.3.1/_pytest/main.py#L126-L128), named `pytest_sessionfinish`, could do this.

consider you have following tests:

```
def test_spam():
    assert 0

def test_ham():
    pass

def test_eggs():
    pass
```

and a hook in conftest.py:

```
import pytest, _pytest

ACCEPTABLE_FAILURE_RATE = 50

@pytest.hookimpl()
def pytest_sessionfinish(session, exitstatus):
    if exitstatus != _pytest.main.EXIT_TESTSFAILED:
        return
    failure_rate = (100.0 * session.testsfailed) / session.testscollected
    if failure_rate <= ACCEPTABLE_FAILURE_RATE:
        session.exitstatus = 0
```

then invoke pytest:

```
$ pytest --tb=no -q tests.py
F..                                                                                        [100%]
1 failed, 2 passed in 0.06 seconds
```

here the failure rate is `1 / 3 == 33.3%`, below 50%:

```
$ echo $?
0
```

you could see the exit status of pytest is 0.

Comment: I have verified this answer with Python 3.7 and pytest 3.6. It works if the tests fail as well if they error (that's what i want anyway).

Comment: @hroncok I guess it is possible to distinguish AssertionError with other types of exception.

Comment: `_pytest.main.EXIT_TESTSFAILED` is gone in pytest 5. now it is `pytest.ExitCode.TESTS_FAILED` - in either case, it is `1`. See https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/5125